# phantom build error (add plugin in webpage.cpp)

Tags: c++, phantomjs

When I add a plugin in `webpage.cpp`:

```
m_customWebPage->settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::JavascriptEnabled,true);
m_customWebPage->settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::PluginsEnabled,true);
m_customWebPage->setPluginFactory(new FWebPluginFactory(this));
```

I receive an error when building phantom in win7. It shows an unresolved external symbol: `FWebPluginFactory`.

Comment: Are you sure that you linked it?

Comment: I have include fwebpluginfactory.h in webpage.cpp

Comment: here is FWebPluginFactory.h file:  pan.baidu.com/s/1pJmrkyZ

Comment: here is FWebPluginFactory.cpp file :   pan.baidu.com/s/1hqIt5re

Comment: It has been resolved . You can get solution in https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/13609